# htaccess selective redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all sub-directory pages to main directory, except of a few pages (e.g. (somepage1.html).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(de|ru)/somepage1.html
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|zh-CN|zh-TW)/(.*)$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

Everything working except de/somepage1.html is redirected to home page (/), which is not acceptable. I wont it not redirected at all.
How can I achieve it
Thanks1

Answer (score 0):

Well above rules are clearly excluding `de/somepage1.html` URL so it is most likely some other rule that is redirecting `de/somepage1.html` to `/`. Are you using wordpress or some other CMS tool by any chance? That might have its own rules in .htaccess file, check that please.

Also it would help to check web server's access log when this redirection happens.

Answer (score 0):

the code I provided is **working** perfectly, so if somebody looking for this kind of a solution can use it without a fought. 
The reason for not working is that my website were keeping cash and therefore was not renew frequently.